# Webdriver randomly produces 'chrome not reachable' on Linux tests

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Our CI tests fail randomly with 'chrome not reachable' error.  Initially they were quite rare, but as our test base grows, it has become intolerable.  There are several other questions / bug reports about this, but none of these seem to relate to our case.

The tests are written with Cucumber + Ruby + Watir-Webdriver + Selenium-Webdriver (latest versions of each gem).  We're running the tests on Ubuntu Linux 12.04 in headless mode using xvfb on physical hardware (no virtualization).  I can reproduce it quite reliably on my laptop running Linux Mint 16.  We're running the tests in parallel for speeding up things.

I've tried using both Chromium 18.0.1025.151~r130497-0ubuntu1 and Google Chrome 34.0.1847.116, with ChromeDriver v2.9.248304.  The same problem has occurred with older versions of the browser and ChromeDriver as well.

Typically several tests fail in a row due to the same error and then is starts working again on a later test during the same run.

The stack trace is:

```
  chrome not reachable
    (Session info: chrome=34.0.1847.116)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248304,platform=Linux 3.2.0-60-generic x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
  /home/weller/jenkins/workspace/TEST_CHROME_C/server/cucumber/support/step_support/browsers.rb:14:in `goto'
  /home/weller/jenkins/workspace/TEST_CHROME_C/server/cucumber/support/step_support/browsers.rb:35:in `blank_page'
  /home/weller/jenkins/workspace/TEST_CHROME_C/server/cucumber/support/step_support/browsers.rb:44:in `add_cookie'
  ./features/support/mocking.rb:11:in `mock'
  ./features/support/time_steps.rb:5:in `/^the current time zone is "(.*?)"$/'
  features/trackers/mood/mood_data_entry.feature:7:in `And the current time zone is "GMT+4"'
```

**Update:**  The problem seems to be related to the parallelism.  When one of the tests exit, there's a chance that another one will start failing with 'chrome not reachable'.  If I add a delay to the end of the tests, so that all tests have finished before any Chrome windows are closed, the tests run without problem.  I [reported a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=795) against ChromeDriver about the issue.

Comment: Intermittent, usually means your network is having intermittent issues. have you tried doing a ping -t www.google.com in a separate command prompt on each computer involved in the test? When I tried that, most of the time I was getting chrome unreachable issues I was seeing connection issues as well.

Comment: The problem occurs on our local network, so I doubt network connectivity to be the issue.  I'll add ping polling just to be sure.

The issue has gotten considerably worse after we added parallelization to our tests (different tests are being run in separate headless Chrome instances).

Comment: I actually meant local network. It's very possible to have internet issues at your own company... What I couldn't figure out is a best workaround for when this happened. If you figure something out, please do post some code :)

Comment: Couldn't find any problems on the network.  I also sometimes get it when running tests on my local laptop against a local environment, so I don't think it has to do with network issues.  It does seem to be related to parallelization, running multiple tests at once.

Comment: The cause is actually closing of the Chrome window in one process while another test process is running.  If I add a delay to the end of the tests, allowing all tests to complete before any browsers are closed, they run fine.  I [reported a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=795) to ChromeDriver.  Any suggestions for workarounds are welcome.

Comment: Ahh in that case it's clearly being caused by a different issue. Can you Edit your original post with that info? it would also help if you post an example test/code that shows your browser setup, browser teardown code, the runner used for parallelism, and a sample testcase. Post it here or via github

Comment: Actually, it's not caused by closing the Chrome window, it's caused by closing the Xvfb instance used by the headless gem (as suggested by @wyh770604).  If I create a single Xvfb instance and reuse that, the tests work mostly, though in some cases I now get "Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)" instead.  Still trying to figure out how to get it to work.

Comment: The problem is that when the driver is closed, the user-data-dir is deleted, and when it's shared by more than 1 webdriver it produces that error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, in my case it was because user-data-dir, which is randomly created by chromedriver, in some cases was the same for several tests. I solved it by synchronizing webdriver creation (performance is not affected by this)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below options,

1) Do not run many Jenkins jobs paralelly
2) Try to use less threads , instead of more threads to create browser.

It will solve your problem.

In-case if you have more tests, you should implement selenium grid.